# angularjs - populating json array from input text ng-model

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a form and I want to send its data to the back end in a json format. The problem I'm having is that some of the form fields should populate an array.

**The short version of the form (using jade template):**

```
div(ng-controller="NewProposalController as newProposal")
    form(name="form", method="POST")
        div
           label Project: 
           input(type="text", ng-model="proposal.project")
        div
           label Contact name:
           input(type="text", ng-model="proposal.contacts[0].name")
           label email:
           input(type="text", ng-model="proposal.contacts[0].email")
        div
           label Contact name:
           input(type="text", ng-model="proposal.contacts[1].name")
           label email:
           input(type="text", ng-model="proposal.contacts[1].email")
        button(ng-click="create(proposal)") Save
```

**Short version of the controller**

```
App.controller('NewProposalController', ['$http', '$scope', '$window',
    function($http, $scope, $window) {
        $scope.master = {};

        $scope.create = function(proposal) {
            $scope.master = angular.copy(proposal);
            $http.post('/proposals/proposal/create', $scope.master)
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $window.location.href = headers('redirectURL');
                    });
        };

    }]);
```

**Expected json to be sent to the server**

```
{
    "project":"Some project name",
    "contacts":[
                  {
                      "name":"John",
                      "email":"john@abc.com"
                  },{
                      "name":"Paul",
                      "email":"paul@abc.com"
                  }
               ]
}
```

However, when I press the "Save" button, I get the following error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

How can I have my contact input texts populating a json property as an array?

Answer (score 0):

in this case you'll need to initialize the proposal object from controller:

```
$scope.master = {};

$scope.proposal = {
    contacts: [
        {
            name: "",
            email: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            email: ""
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: I wonder if there is something related to the $scope being injected.

Comment: Adding the following to a div worked:   `ng-init="newProposal.contacts = [{name:'', email:''},{name:'', email:''}]"`

Comment: Read "proposal.contacts" instead of "newProposal.contacts" in the comment above.